# How to break down insights by day via Facebook api

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I want to get the daily insights data so I try to use the below edge to request record by record (day by day). If there is data for 30 days, I have to request 30 times.

**/insights?fields=impressions,social_clicks,website_clicks,ctr&time_range={'since':'2015-01-01','until':'2015-01-01'}**

But if I can break down by using the edge such as the below one, I would not have to request many times.

**/insights?fields=impressions,social_clicks,website_clicks,ctr&breakdowns=DAY**

Do you know how to break down the insights by day?

Comment: You don't seem to be asking a question about programming. Did you try googling for "Facebook Ads Insights API"?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights-api

Answer (score 32):

You can select how to break in days using a parameter, for getting daily info just use the parameter `time_increment` parameter with value 1.

```
/insights?fields=impressions,social_clicks,website_clicks,ctr&time_range={'since':'2015-01-01','until':'2015-01-30'}&time_increment=1
```

Reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/